# rsync redoing files?

Tags: rsync

I found rsync redoing files that have no modification. One file is >1gb so it takes a bit to do. My command is below. I'm running the command via ssh. The filesystem in question is a NTFS usb HDD to a ext3 filesystem. Both connected to the same virtual machine running ubuntu

```
rsync --stats --progress -r src dst
```

Comment: Always use `rsync -a` unless you know there's something you don't want to preserve. Without any options, you're asking `rsync` to not preserve times, so it can't use the modification time as an optimization not to copy the file the second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you don't have permissions to set the modification times on the destination, you should see this if it is happening when you explicitly use `rsync -t`.

Also, you may want to account for variances since some data is lost in the transition from Unix to NTFS mtimes: `--modify-window=2` should do the job.

Comment: ah, -t fixed it. I can't believe that isnt enabled by default.

Comment: Why would one make behaviour that's required non-linux file-systems the default for a linux tool?

Comment: @tink was that at me? I am using linux and it thinks the file didnt change because i didnt include `-t`

Comment: @acidzombie24 Yes, but NTFS is a non-Linux filesystem. That's the point he's making.

Comment: I see. Then how does it know if a file was modified or not?